# Requesting ID tokens in Java

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am developing a Spring Boot REST API which uses Firebase for authentication (i.e, it uses the Admin SDK to verify passed ID tokens). I use the standard Firebase ID tokens without custom authentication.

The Spring AuthenticationProvider

```
@Component
class FirebaseAuthenticationProvider(private val firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth) :
        AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider() {

    override fun supports(authentication: Class<*>?): Boolean {
        return FirebaseAuthenticationToken::class.java.isAssignableFrom(authentication)
    }

    override fun retrieveUser(username: String?, authentication: UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken?): UserDetails {
        var firebaseAuthenticationToken = authentication as FirebaseAuthenticationToken

        val task = firebaseAuth.verifyIdTokenAsync(firebaseAuthenticationToken.token)

        try {
            val firebaseToken = task.get()
            return FirebaseUserDetails(firebaseToken.email, firebaseToken.uid)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            when (e) {
                is InterruptedException, is ExecutionException -> {
                    throw SessionAuthenticationException(e.message)
                }
                else -> throw e
            }
        }

    }

    override fun additionalAuthenticationChecks(userDetails: UserDetails?,
                                                authentication: UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken?) {
        // nothing to do here
    }

}
```

I want to integrationtest the components that extract the token and verify it via the Admin SDK. For that I want to simulate an Android client and retrieve a fresh ID token for a test user on each test run.

For example

```
@Test
fun `accepts valid token`() {

    // HOW TO DO THIS       
    val testToken: String = ???????????

    println("Acquired token $testToken")

    mockMvc.perform(get("/").header(FirebaseAuthenticationTokenFilter.TOKEN_HEADER, testToken))
            .andExpect(status().isOk)   
}
```

How can I retrieve a valid ID token in pure Java, given a correct email and password?

I tried to use the IdentityToolkit REST API

```
private fun getTokenForTestUser() : String {
    val restClient = RestTemplate()
    val json = JSONObject().put("email", testUsername).put("password", testPassword)
    val headers = HttpHeaders()
    headers.contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON
    headers.accept = listOf(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    val request = HttpEntity(json.toString(), headers)

    val response = restClient.postForObject(
            "https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=$testApiKey",
            request, Map::class.java) as Map<String, String>

    return response["idToken"]!!
}
```

This does not work though, as the retrieved tokens lack the required issuer field.

Comment: please share any code snippet of how you're currently doing it and what exactly you're expecting?

Comment: @S1LENTWARRIOR I edited my question to include some code snippets.